# Getting npm error while deploying a Next.js app on heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js

I am trying to deploy a Next.js application on heroku, but during project build it gives error "npm ERR! path /tmp/build_e888593abeb04bd0ba3c83c3147db89b/node_modules/websocket"

I found a solution that says to remove the .git folder from the node_modules/websocket directory. But there is not .git folder in the above mentioned directory.

```
   npm ERR! path /tmp/build_e888593abeb04bd0ba3c83c3147db89b/node_modules/websocket
   npm ERR! code EISGIT
   npm ERR! git /tmp/build_e888593abeb04bd0ba3c83c3147db89b/node_modules/websocket: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
   npm ERR! git     /tmp/build_e888593abeb04bd0ba3c83c3147db89b/node_modules/websocket
   npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
   npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.mTr1h/_logs/2019-05-08T16_02_03_118Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Run `heroku run bash` to get into a bash terminal where you would have access to your project’s files

2) Then `rm -rf node_modules` to completely delete the node_modules directory.

3) Exit bash.

4) Run `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` to ensure Heroku doesn’t try to use a cache in rebuilding your node_modules.

If this resolved it, you should set `node_modules_cache` back to `true`.